# dplyr coerces characters to factors

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm sure there's a great reason for this that I am not finding at the moment, but ... why does dplyr coerce characters to factors, even when you explicitly coerce to character?

```
> letters
 [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i" "j" "k" "l" "m" "n" "o" "p" "q" "r" "s" "t" "u" "v" "w" "x" "y" "z"
> typeof(letters)
[1] "character"
> data.frame(
+   colA = as.character(letters), 
+   colB = as.character(LETTERS)
+ ) %>%
+   glimpse
Observations: 26
Variables: 2
$ colA <fct> a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z
$ colB <fct> A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X, Y, Z
```

Answer (score 5):

It is not the `dplyr` that coerce it to `factor`, but is the `data.frame` (`base R` constructor), where the default option is `stringsAsFactors = TRUE`.  Specifying `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` will rectify the issue

```
data.frame(
  colA = letters, 
  colB = LETTERS, stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

NOTE: There is no need to wrap `as.character`

---

As we are using `tidyverse`, an option is `tibble`, which will have the default setting of `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`

```
tibble(colA = letters, colB = LETTERS)
```

Comment: yup, knew it was simple just couldn't remember what was going on.  apologies for mixing my issues with tidyverse and base R `data.frame`; am working with a dplyr pipe and saw this behavior then i made a crappy example.

Comment: think i should leave this up? couldn't really find another question like it, but probably a duplicate given I was searching for "dplyr" behavior...

Comment: @d8aninja  That is up to you to leave it as such.  It would be a dupe if the search is not made on dplyr

Comment: i'll leave it up.  maybe other tired r programmers will have made the same mistake in their searches :)